# Minkowski distance and pdist

Tags: matlab, distance, pdist

Minkowski's distance equation can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance).

If we want to calculate the Minkowski distance in `MATLAB`, I think we can do the following (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
dist=pdist([x(i);y(j)],'minkowski');
```

Up till here, the above command will do the equation shown in the link.

Now, to Minkowski's distance, I want to add this part `|-m(i)|^p`, where `m(i)` is some value.

I saw the `pdist` source code, but, want to ask, how can I modify Minkowski's distance by adding this simple part, either in the `pdist` code, or from the calling code (I think we may have to make some change in the parameters).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to include that part _within_ the summation that defines Minkowski's distance?

Comment: @Luis Mendo. Thanks for your reply. It will be added to the summation. In other words, it will be with the summation under the root

Comment: But your term depends in `i`, so |-m(i)|^m will give a _vector_, whereas `dist=pdist([x(i);y(j)],'minkowski')` gives a _single number_, right? What are the sizes of `x`,`y`?

Comment: Also, if `m` depends on `i`, what exactly is the exponent `^m`?

Comment: @Luis Mendo. Sorry, for the exponent `m`, I mean `p` as shown in the equation in wikipedia (I changed that in the question). x(i) represents a point in the matrix, and c(i) represents a cluster center. Those will be in a loop, so, yes, every time they will return a number. Likewise for `m(i)`, which will return a number as it is also part of a loop. So, for `x` and `y`, where are actually trying to calculate the distance between a point and a cluster center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want: define a custom distance function and use it as an argument to `pdist`:

```
p = 2;
fun = @(x,y) sum(abs(x-y).^p + abs(m(i)).^p ).^(1/p);
pdist([x(i);y(j)],fun)
```

Or directly use

```
sum(abs(x(i)-y(j)).^p + abs(m(i)).^p ).^(1/p)
```

I'm assuming `i` and `j` are just indices that run through the elements of `x` and `y`.

Comment: So, this part `sum(abs(x(i)-y(j)).^p).^(1/p)` would be the `Minkowski distance, right? So, I don't need to call `pdist` for instance? And, yes, regarding `i` and `j`, they are simply indices that run through `x` and `y`, resectively

Comment: Yes, `sum(abs(x(i)-y(j)).^p).^(1/p)` gives the same result as `pdist([x(i);y(j)],'minkowski')`